# Iterating over first n elements of 2d array in Python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have initialised an empty 2d array as follows:

```
matrixLength = (len(a)+1)*(len(b)+1)

matrix = []
    step = []

    for i in range(matrixLength):
        matrix.append(step)
```

when I print it, it gives me this:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

so far so good. But when I want to iterate over the first Len(a) elements of the 2d array, with the following code:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)+1):
        print(i)
        matrix[i].append(i)

print (matrix)
```

instead of getting an array with only the first len(a) elements filled, like this:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

I get this instead:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

why?

Comment: They are all the same list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Though not exactly the same, but essentially is a dupe.

Comment: got it! cheers guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `step` to `[]` you create a reference to one instance of the list type, so when you append `matrix` with `step` you put the same reference in all positions. You can easily verify this by printing all matrix element id:

```
for el in matrix:     
    print(id(el))
```

You need to create a different list for each element:

```
matrixLength = (len(a)+1)*(len(b)+1)                   
matrix = []
for i in range(matrixLength):     
     matrix.append(list())
```

Then you'll be able to update each list independently.